# data.table aggregation by one column using the maximum value of another column - R

Tags: r, data.table, max, aggregate

I've got a data.table DT that I would like to aggregate by one column (year) using the maximum value of another column (month). Here's a sample of my data.table.

```
> DT <- data.table(month = c("2016-01", "2016-02", "2016-03", "2017-01", "2017-02", "2017-03")
                  , col1 = c(3,5,2,8,4,9)
                  , year = c(2016, 2016,2016, 2017,2017,2017))

> DT
     month col1 year
1: 2016-01    3 2016
2: 2016-02    5 2016
3: 2016-03    2 2016
4: 2017-01    8 2017
5: 2017-02    4 2017
6: 2017-03    9 2017
```

The desired output

```
> ## desired output
    > DT
         month col1 year desired_output
    1: 2016-01    3 2016     2
    2: 2016-02    5 2016     2
    3: 2016-03    2 2016     2
    4: 2017-01    8 2017     9
    5: 2017-02    4 2017     9
    6: 2017-03    9 2017     9
```

Aggregating by the column year, the desired output should be the value of col1 for the latest month. But somehow the following code doesn't work, it gives me a warning and returns NAs. What am I doing wrong?

```
> ## wrong output
 > DT[, output := col1[which.max(month)], by = .(year)]
    Warning messages:
    1: In which.max(month) : NAs introduced by coercion
    2: In which.max(month) : NAs introduced by coercion
> DT
     month col1 year output
1: 2016-01    3 2016     NA
2: 2016-02    5 2016     NA
3: 2016-03    2 2016     NA
4: 2017-01    8 2017     NA
5: 2017-02    4 2017     NA
6: 2017-03    9 2017     NA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We get the index of the max value in 'month by converting to `yearmon` class from `zoo` and use that to get the corresponding value from 'col1' in creating the 'desired_output' column grouped by 'year'

```
library(zoo)
library(data.table)
DT[, desired_output := col1[which.max(as.yearmon(month))], .(year)]
DT
#     month col1 year desired_output
#1: 2016-01    3 2016              2
#2: 2016-02    5 2016              2
#3: 2016-03    2 2016              2
#4: 2017-01    8 2017              9
#5: 2017-02    4 2017              9
#6: 2017-03    9 2017              9
```

---

Or extract the 'month' and get the index of `max` value

```
DT[, desired_output := col1[which.max(month(as.IDate(paste0(month,
                  "-01"))))], .(year)]
```

Comment: so, which.max doesn't work on string columns? max(DT$month) works, but not which.max(DT$month)

Comment: it seems which.max only works on numeric values. Thanks so much for your help, it makes sense now. Would be nice to extend which.max functionality to character variables too

Comment: For `Date`  objects, it is better to apply on `Date` class to avoid any issues.